# Is there a way to draw UILabel diagonally?

Tags: iphone, uilabel

How do you draw text on a diagonal?  In other words, a horizontal UILabel that's rotated, say, 45 degrees?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
// rotate 45 degrees
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 4);
```

You may want to do this before adding the label to its parent view.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a CGAffineTransform to rotate the view.

```
myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45 * M_PI / 180);
```

Comment: Posting from an iPad is obviously too slow when writing code is needed. There were no answers when I started posting. Now there are 3 :(

Comment: This is the most idiomatic answer. The formula to convert from degrees to radians is degrees * pi/180. So this one reads "rotate 45 degrees" better than the others.

Answer (score 4):

Why no one mentioned M_PI_4 (constant for PI/4)?

```
myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4);
```

It's the fastest way 'cause it does not require division :)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/math.3.html

Comment: Would generate the exact same code though, since the expression is constant it will evaluate at compile time. So no speed difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can `.transform` the label, e.g.

```
theLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 4);   // pi/4 = 45 degrees.
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3:

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 4))
```